# MongoDB PHP Driver not loaded in fpm - but loaded in cli

Tags: php, mongodb, command-line-interface, fpm

The system and tools installed on are the following ones:

- Linux server `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`
- `php7.0`
- `mongoDB version v3.2.12`
- `mongoDB php driver 1.2.5`.

And I have carefully added `extension=mongodb.so` in both `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`.

Then I have a document `info.php` which contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

So `php -f info.php` return that mongoDB is correctly loaded, and I can instantiate the various classes and play with them.

But if load the file into a web browser `www.myserver.com/info.php`, I cannot find the mongoDB section. And indeed all mongoDB-PHP-driver code fails.

Is it because **MongoDB-php-driver is not correctly installed for the php/fpm ?** Or is it because **MongoDB itself is not correctly installed ?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you restart fpm after amending the ini file? Did you check the logs after restarting?

Comment: @symcbean you are my hero. So I just did `sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service`, refreshed the webpage, and it worked. Hahaha awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service` to restart.